# Angular Select2 formatResult not updating the template

Tags: angularjs, templates, updates, ui-select2

I have a select2 drop down with the following markup:

```
<select id="selectByName" ui-select2="select2Options" ng-model="selectId" data-placeholder="Select item by name" style="width:250px">
  <option></option>
  <option ng-repeat='item in items' data-show="{{item.show}}" value="{{item.id}}">
    {{item.name}}
  </option>       
</select>
```

And the js contains the following:

`$scope.items` (an array that has a id, a boolean show property and a name property)

and the select 2 options:

```
select2Options : {
       allowClear: true,
       placeholder:"select a value",
       formatResult: function(state) {
          var $elem = angular.element(state.element),
          isVisible = $elem.data('show');
          return isVisible ? '<span style="color:red">'+state.text+'</span>':
                              <span style="color:blue">'+state.text+'</span>';

       }
 },
```

Well, the `ng-repeat` updates correctly the html markup and sets data-show attribute to either true or false, but the `formatResult` function does not update this value.
In the html source the `data-show="true"` and in the `formatResult` function `$elem.data('show') = false;`, why doesn't it update while the function is called every time the select2 is opened?

Here is made a plunker that illustrates my question: [plnkr.co/edit/d0LxuhzdQh7hMdzOoxpr?p=preview](http://plnkr.co/edit/d0LxuhzdQh7hMdzOoxpr?p=preview) .It looks the formatResult updates the results correctly only once before opening the select2 for the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

http://plnkr.co/edit/6Vma1WTQWQw0HAIQUVxE?p=preview

```
  $scope.select2options = {
    allowClear: true,
    placeholder: "select a value",
    formatResult: function(state, container) {
      var $elem = angular.element(state.element);
      var scope = $elem.data('$scope');
      if (scope !== undefined) {
        isVisible = scope.$eval($elem.data('show'));
        $scope.dataShow[$elem.attr('value')] = isVisible;
        $scope.updated++;
        return isVisible ? '<span style="color:red">' + state.text + '</span>' :
          ' <span style="color:blue">' + state.text + '</span>'
      }
    }
  }
```

The key part is grabbing the `$scope` data from the jqLite element and then calling `$eval`, which evaluates an unparsed string expression in the context of the scope.  If we had used `$scope.$eval`, it would have used the controller `$scope`, which wouldn't have the `ng-repeat` on it.  By grabbing it from the element we have a scope that has access to the `item` property for the `ng-repeat`.

Having said that I don't recommend using this code (sometimes jQuery widgets force you into unpleasant corners when working with angular).  Again if you find yourself manipulating `angular.element` or using `$element` in a controller you probably should use a directive instead.  Then again we programmers have to deal with non-ideal constraints (time, money, etc.) that prevent us from working "ideally" so given your context this may be a decent solution.

Let me know if any of my explanation doesn't make sense.

**Original**

http://plnkr.co/edit/vYTdxPwgwqZSgK5m9yk9?p=preview

Is this what you want?

*JavaScript*

```
  $scope.items = [{
    id: 1,
    show: false,
    name: 'test1'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    show: true,
    name: 'test2'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    show: true,
    name: 'test3'
  }];

  $scope.selections = [1, 2];

  $scope.getStyleForIndex = function (index) {
    var item;
    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.items.length; i++) {
      if (i === index) {
        item = $scope.items[i];
        break;
      }
    }

    return item.show ? { color: "red" } : { color: "blue" };
  }

  $scope.select2options = {
    allowClear: true,
    formatResult: function(item, container) {
      var color = $scope.getStyleForIndex(parseInt(item.id, 10)).color;
      container.html('<span style="color:' + color  + '">RESULT ' + item.text + '</span>');
    },
    formatSelection: function(item, container) {
      container.append($compile('<span ng-style="getStyleForIndex(' + item.id + ')">SELECTION ' + item.text + '</span>')($scope));
    }
  }
```

*HTML*

```
  <div ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item.name }}  
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.show" />
  </div>

  <select ui-select2="select2options" ng-model="selections" style="width:200px" multiple="true" ng-options="i.id as i.name for i in items"></select>
  {{selections}}
```

Comment: I avoided to use hg-options as recommended on: [link](http://https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select2): ui-select2 is incompatible with <select ng-options>. For the best results use <option ng-repeat> instead. I also avoided getting back the original "item" because in the example above for simplicity I used a 3 element array. In fact I have a much bigger amount of data and this is why I tried to embed some extra data in the html markup for styling, so I don't have to get back the original item.

Comment: I would gladly like to mark your answer, for which I thank you very much, as the needed one but, I still hope someone can shed some light on the specific issue I am pointing here. Why the data-show, is not getting updated in the formatResultFunction.

Comment: @vladblindu  I don't like putting formatting code inside my controllers.  I think views and directives are for that.  That said, does this do what you want?  http://plnkr.co/edit/6Vma1WTQWQw0HAIQUVxE?p=preview

Comment: YES!!! - that's what I call a perfect answer. Thanks a lot. If you have a few moments to explain the $scope & $eval part in the formatResult function I would be really grateful

Comment: @vladblindu I added the explanation in the answer for future readers.

Comment: Thank you again. I recognise I feel I'm only scratching the surface of Angular js after your explanation. I understand what you did, but to tell you the truth, it's way In front of what I thought it's all about. I definitely hope it will help more advanced programers by being posted here. On the other hand, while struggling with this issue I found out that isVisible = state.element[0].getAttribute("data-show") does the trick also. But my solution looks childish compared to yours anyway.